# Timed out trying to acquire network configuration lock, current owner = 'iphlpsvc.dll'

Tags: windows, hyper-v, windows-8.1

I am getting the above error when trying to configure Hyper-V virtual switches. This happened no matter what type of switch I try to create.

```
PS C:\Users\Martin> New-VMSwitch -Name “NewSwitch” -NetAdapterName “WiFi” -AllowManagementOS $True 
New-VMSwitch : Failed while creating virtual Ethernet switch.
Switch create failed, name = '326B5310-CEB9-4E87-AB36-DD2DD9602A73', friendly name = '': Operation times out (0x80041069).
Timed out trying to acquire network configuration lock, current owner = 'iphlpsvc.dll'.
The operation timed out.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-VMSwitch -Name “NewSwitch” -NetAdapterName “WiFi” -AllowManagementOS $True
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationTimeout: (Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.VMTask:VMTask) [New-VMSwitch], VirtualizationOperationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : OperationTimeout,Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.NewVMSwitchCommand
```

Any help would be very much appreciated as I could not find anything online.

Answer (score 0):

The file referenced is the "IP Helper" service. Stop the service with `net stop iphlpsvc` and try your switch command.

Note: stopping this service will deactivate the Teredo 6to4 tunnel, but if you don't use it, it's nothing to worry about.